# Presentations for monoidal $\infty$ categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory, model-categories

Are there any references for model categorical presentations of the $(\infty,1)$ category of (not necessarily symmetric) monoidal $\infty$-categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 4.1.4.7 in Lurie's Higher Algebra shows that
the underlying quasicategory of
the model category of monoids in marked simplicial sets
is equivalent to the quasicategory of small symmetric monoidal ∞-categories.